# Hiding and revealing divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, event-binding

I've a script which works fine when written like this:

```
var isPaused = false,
jQuery(function () {
    var $els = $('div[id^=film]'),
        i = 0,
        len = $els.length;

    $els.slice(1).hide();
    setInterval(function () {
        if (!isPaused) {
            if (len > 1) {
                $els.eq(i).fadeOut(function () {
                    i = (i + 1) % len;
                    $els.eq(i).fadeIn();
                    });
            }
        }
    }, 3500);
});
```

But I wanted to add a next and prev button so I rewrote like this, which I thought would work.

```
var isPaused = false,
    $els = $('div[id^=film]'),
    i = 0,
    len = $els.length;

    $els.slice(1).hide();
    setInterval(Slide(1), 3500);

function Slide (x) {
    if (!isPaused) {
        if (len > 1) {
            $els.eq(i).fadeOut(function () {
                i = (i + x) % len;
                if (i<0) {
                    i = len;
                }
                $els.eq(i).fadeIn();
                });
        }
    }
}

$('#next').click(Slide(1));
$('#prev').click(Slide(-1));
```

But this code is just displaying all the divs when the page is loaded and then doesn't fade them in and out or allow the next and prev buttons to work.  What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
Perhaps I should ask this differently.  Given the first block of code, how should I change it to enable Prev and Next buttons?

Comment: Seeing as the `Slide()` function doesn't return anything at all, you're doing `$('#next').click(undefined)` <- yes, it's exactly like that, no wonder it doesn't do anything.

Comment: use anonymus function
var Slide = function (x) {}

Comment: Any issue showed on console?

Comment: No issues in console

Comment: As mentioned elsewhere, you can't do `setInterval(myFunction(param)...`, you'd need to do it anonymously... `setInterval(function() {myFunction(param)}...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do:

```
$('#next').click(function(){Slide(1);});
$('#prev').click(function(){Slide(-1);});
```

and

```
setInterval(function(){Slide(1);}, 3500);
```

instead, as with your current code, `Slide(1)` is already being computed, and the click function will just call the value returned from it (as it has no return in the function, this will not be defined)

By wrapping your calls to Slide in a function, this makes the clicks call that function, which in turn calls Slide

You also want to set your index to `len - 1` if you go negative, rather than to `len`, as you're dealing with a zero indexed array:

```
if (i<0) {
    i = len - 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this but it is making no difference

Comment: @HenryM Noticed that you also need an anonymous function for setInterval, and an issue with your slide function. This seems to be working in my fiddle as I believe you want it to.

Comment: Can you show me the fiddle because I'm just getting all the divs loading in one go and not moving when I click the button

Comment: Thanks, but it isn't working for me with the rest of my code and I cannot understand why.  For some reason my divs are all showing at the same time.  I'll work through it and in the meantime consider this answered because it does show a working solution

Comment: @HenryM Might be worth looking into how you're identifying the divs, as that is likely different from my example.

Comment: My divs are numbered Film1, Film2 etc because I'm using them for something else and I'm creating the html through a Django template.  You can see how I'm identifying them which works when the identified within the JQuery

Answer (score 0):

You jQuery event callbacks must be inside a load structure like:

```
// Wait for DOM load
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#next').click(function(){ Slide(1); });
  $('#prev').click(function(){ Slide(-1); });
});
```

And I would like to suggest you to change your:

```
setInterval(Slide(1), 3500);
```

to

```
setInterval(function() { 
  Slide(1); 
}, 3500);
```

Hope it helps